# Can't receive backMessage with sockets

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets

I decided to create quite a stupid system to set correct endpoints to send bytes arrays to. Here, how it works:
If you are host, you are waiting for message "Here!" from the guy who is connecting. If you are connecting, you send the "Here!" message.
After host gets the "Here!" message, he sends the "Yeah!" message back and the connecting guy is trying to receive it.
It all works on ReceiveFrom() and it refs to endPoint to send other information using it.
The host gets "Here!" message amazingly, but doesn't sends backMessage or connector doesn't receive backMessage. Please, help me with it.
Here is all the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            port = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

            IP = IPAddress.Parse(textBox1.Text);

            Game game = new Game();
            game.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.Controls.Add(game);
            Controls.Remove(this);
            game.BringToFront();
            try
            {
                sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

                string message = "Here!";

                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
                EndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IP, port);
                sock.SendTo(data, endPoint);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                Close();
            }

            thread = new Thread(Game.Multiplayer);
            thread.Start();

            sock.Close();
        }

while (!gameStarted && isHost)
            {
                try
                {
                    localIp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Menu.port);
                    sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                    sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
                    sock.Bind(localIp);

                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting For Players...");
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    int bytes = 0;
                    byte[] data = new byte[256 * 10000];

                    endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine(endPoint);

                    do
                    {
                        bytes = sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref endPoint);
                        Console.WriteLine(endPoint);
                        builder.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                    }
                    while (sock.Available > 0);

                    if (builder.ToString() == "Here!")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Game Started!");
                        try
                        {
                            string backMessage = "Yeah!";

                            byte[] backData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(backMessage);
                            sock.SendTo(backData, endPoint);

                            sock.Close();
                            gameStarted = true;
                        }
                        catch (Exception exc)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            Menu.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    Menu.Close();
                }
            }

while(!isHost && !gameStarted)
            {
                try
                {
                    localIp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Menu.port);
                    sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                    sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
                    sock.Bind(localIp);

                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting For Answer...");
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    int bytes = 0;
                    byte[] data = new byte[256 * 10000];

                    endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

                    do
                    {
                        bytes = sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref endPoint);
                        Console.WriteLine(bytes.ToString());
                        builder.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                    }
                    while (sock.Available > 0);

                    if (builder.ToString() == "Yeah!")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Game Started!");
                        sock.Close();
                        gameStarted = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    Menu.Close();
                }
            }
```

Sorry, if i misunderstand something about sockets. I hope, you guys help me

Comment: Does it work if the host doesn't close the socket right after sending the message?

Comment: I noticed that you're using UDP but you're treating it like TCP. UDP transmits datagrams. If the sender sends 48 65 72 65 21 in a single `SendTo` call, you get those 5 bytes in a single `ReceiveFrom` call. You don't need a loop to reconstruct a complete datagram.

Comment: @user253751 no, it doesn't

Comment: @madreflection then, how to set correct endpoints to send bytes to? i'm creating sort of a game and i want to host only typed in port